# iOS app submisson to Apple store with otp registration

Tags: ios

I have an app which will use OTP (one-time password) value send via SMS for registration similar to Whatsapp registration process kind.
But during app submission process I'm supposed to give a demo mobile number.

If I give a demo account, then how will the Apple reviewer enter the OTP for registration?

Comment: Did you submit your app?

Answer (score 0):

Just explain it in the notes field when you submit the app. If you explain it clearly enough, they will get it and everything will be good!!